# problems with s7-1200 modbus TCP/IP SATUS 7006 ALWAYS

Tags: plc, siemens, tia-portal

I try to read registers through a modbus client in an s7-1200, I have tried to follow the siemens guide and it seems that all the parameters are correct, nothing seems strange, it always gives me status 7006 and the busy bit is always 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps but I had the same problem connecting to Arduino TCP/IP Modbus. The problem was solved by setting the RemotePort to 502. First make sure if every thing else sets right.